# How to do FFT on signal of different period

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, fft, fftpack

I need to perform FFT on gait signals that are not strictly periodic. Below is the code I created for double and single sided. However, I do not know if it is right as the signal is not strictly periodic -- people walk differently every step. If I sample the same number of samples each period, then I do not know what to give fftpack.fftfreq( n, d ) parameter d. Right now I set the d as the time elapse between samples. If I created same number of samples each period, then the d will be changing.

Not sure what to do. Are there existing code here?

```
def plotDoubleSidedSpectrum(y,timestep,SigName,xlimit):

 n=len(y)
 FFT = fftpack.fft(y)
 freqs = fftpack.fftfreq(n,d=timestep) 

 print(FFT)

 fig,ax=plt.subplots()
 ax.plot(freqs,np.abs(FFT)/n,'r') 
 ax.set_xlabel(SigName+ ': Double Sided Frequency in Hertz [Hz]')
 ax.set_ylabel('Frequency Domain (Spectrum) Magnitude')
 ax.set_xlim(-xlimit, xlimit)




def plotSingleSidedSpectrum(y,timestep,SigName,xlimit):

 n=len(y)
 FFT = fftpack.fft(y)
 freqs = fftpack.fftfreq(n,d=timestep) 
 freqSingle = freqs[:n//2]
 AmpSingle = 2*np.abs(FFT[:n//2])/n  # divided by n is to normalize it

 fig,ax=plt.subplots()
 ax.plot(freqSingle,AmpSingle,'r') 
 ax.set_xlabel(SigName+':Single Sided Frequency in Hertz [Hz]')
 ax.set_ylabel('Frequency Domain (Spectrum) Magnitude')
 ax.set_xlim(0,xlimit)
```

Comment: If you have N samples per period, then you can set d=1/N, and the units will be 1/period.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Are there any existing code to take exactly N sample per period and then perform FFT? I am a newbie, thinking about the code to find peaks of the signal and then understand the time difference between peaks and then do interpolation, etc. seems quite hard.

Comment: Yes, it is not trivial. But I don't think I understand why you would want to do this... Are you trying to use the FFT for gait identification? If so, wouldn't you want to include any irregularities in the step durations? What signal are you working with?

Answer (score 0):

d = should be one over the sampling frequency.  This will allow your results to show you the frequencies of the gait, and those variations will help you see the differences in the gait patterns.